# Retrieving multiple values via PHP/jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using the following jQuery to retrieve values for a 'Live Search' field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*  LIVE SEARCH CODE - START HERE*/
var UserID = ('<?php echo $_SESSION['UserID'] ?>');
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clLiveSearchAccount').on("keyup" , "[id*=txtAccountID]", "input", function(){
    /* Get input value on change */
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var ParentTransID = $(this).prev().val();
    alert(UserID);
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
        $.get("Apps/Finance/incGetAccounts.php", {term: inputVal, usr: UserID }).done(function(data){
        // Display the returned data in browser
        resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
    $(this).parents(".clLiveSearchAccount").find('#txtAccountID').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
```

I'm using this PHP ajax handler:

```
<?php
    /* ------------------------------------------------ */
    $link = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['term']);
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['usr']);

    if(isset($term)){
    // Attempt select query execution
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAccounts WHERE Name LIKE '%" . $term . "%' AND UserID=" . $user;
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<p>" . $row['Name'] . "</p>";
        }
        // Close result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
        echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);   

?>
```

But how do I send back (and accept) an additional value, so the String Name and Integer Key?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking to send JSON data.  Put the HTML you want to echo in a variable.

```
$html ="<h1>PHP is Awesome</h1>";
$myVariable = 3;
echo json_encode(array( 'variable1' => $myVariable, 'html' => $html ));
```

and you'll need a success callback in your javascript

```
success: function($data) {
    var html = $data.html;
    var myVar = $data.variable1;

    // other stuff
 }
```

look up a tutorial on PHP JSON
W3schools always a good place to start
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

I always do this return format in ajax.

## Success Response

// PHP

```
$result = [
    'success' => true,
    'variable' => $myVariable,
    'html' => $html,
];
```

## Fail Response

// PHP

```
$result = [
    'success' => false,
    'err_message' => 'Error message here!',
],
```

use json encode when returning the data to the ajax example `json_encode($result)` and also dont forget to add dataType setting in your ajax so that it will expect json format response.

## Ajax fn

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path to php file',
    type: '' // specify the method request here i.e POST/GET
    data: {} // data to be send
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(res) {
        if (res.success) {
           ...
        } else {
           // you can put the error message in html by accessing res.err_message
        }
    }
});
```